# Criminal pitfalls for Westerners in Dubai

Tags: legal, uae, local-customs

What issues should Westerners take care with when in an outplacement in Dubai? What acceptable behaviour in the EU could send you to prison in Dubai?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head

- Public display of affection.
- Public intoxication.
- Wearing provocative clothing in public.
- You need prescriptions for medications.
- Homosexuality and extramarital affairs.
- Possession of pornographic material.
- I read somewhere that dancing in public is considered inappropriate.

You can google "Things not to do in Dubai" for more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There are a series of scary news about expats being put in prison for things that are not criminalized in the west:

- [Austrian rape victim was arrested for having sex outside of marriage](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2549707/Austrian-rape-victim-arrested-having-sex-outside-marriage-UAE-reported-crime-told-MARRY-attacker.html)
- [British man Jamie Harron sentenced to jail for touching man's hip](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/brit-trapped-dubai-jail-after-11334023)
- [Brit sentenced to a month in jail in Dubai](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4969890/Brit-sentenced-month-jail-Dubai-drinking.html)